# SQL translation into Relational Algebra NOT IN

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I have the Uni-Schema which can be found here http://hyper-db.com/interface.html#

i try to translate the following SQL Code into Relational Algebra

```
select distinct s.*, h.vorlnr
from studenten s inner join hoeren h on s.matrnr = h.matrnr
    where h.vorlnr not in (select v.vorgaenger from voraussetzen v)
```

my try is :

π<sub>s.*</sub>(
           p<sub>s</sub>(studenten) ⋈<sub>s.matrnr=h.matrnr</sub> p<sub>h</sub>(hoeren) 
                     ⋈ <sub>h.vorlnr=v.vorgaenger</sub>
p<sub>v</sub>(π<sub>v1.vorgaenger</sub>(
                           voraussetzen -
σ<sub>h1.vorlnr!=v1.vorgaenger</sub>(p<sub>v1</sub>(voraussetzen) x
p<sub>h1</sub>(hoeren))))

is that right ? if not why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is right (y) because it is right